# Backup my documents via command prompt

Tags: windows-7

I have a problem booting a new upgraded windows 7 from vista. It will not load the OS at all, it just stucks at a black screen with a blinking dash top-left.

bootrec /fixboot tells me (The volume does not contain a recognized file system.)
bcdedit shows me the following:

Windows boot loader

> identifier --
>
> device  --  partition=C:
>
> path  --  \Windows\system32\winload.exe
>
> description --   Windows 7 Ultimate
>
> osdevice --  partition=C:
>
> systemroot -- \Windows

I have a windows vista dvd. How can i use that to backup stuff from my documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To backup the documents for your user account:

```
XCOPY C:\Users\[your_username] [destination] /S
```

Where `[destination]` specifies where you'd like them copied, `F:\backup` for example.

Comment: found that i needed to add an /E to copy sub dirs

Comment: /E will copy all subdirectories, even empty ones. If you want to exclude empty ones use /S.

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
XCOPY C:\Users\%username% X:\BackUp\%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%%time:~9,2%_%username% /s
```

Comment: You should explain what it does.

Comment: That's XCOPY "My Documents" to destination with CURRENT DATE TIME. For example; "C:\Users\HORIZON" will be copied as "X:\BackUp\20121106_191020_HORIZON"